# How does the Javadoc deal with the visibility of modules in Java 9?

Tags: java, javadoc, java-9, java-platform-module-system, java-module

The Javadoc tool generates documentation based on the accessibility modifier. By default, it document all `public` and `protected` classes, fields and methods. This can be changed with the following [options](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html):

> -public
>   Shows only public classes and members.
>
> -protected
>   Shows only protected and public classes and members. This is the default.
>
> -package
>   Shows only package, protected, and public classes and members.
>
> -private
>   Shows all classes and members.

Java 9 introduces the concept of modules, and project Jigsaw applies it to the existing JDK. A [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fxB9cVNcyZo) by Mark Reinhold (3rd in a series of talks about modules) shows how the `public` modifier now has different levels of accessibility, depending on the visibility of the module (via `exports`):

> - public to everyone
> - public but only to specific modules
> - public only within a module

Since now not all public members are accessible, it would make less sense to continue with the same Javadoc generation scheme. Only members which are exposed with a "sufficient" level should be documented.

Is the Javadoc module-aware? Are there command options in addition to the ones above to handle the extra exposure layer? For public members which are exposed only to specific modules, does the Javadoc list these, as in

```
public <module1, module2> static void getDefaultThing()
```

?

Comment: Interesting question, especially as the purpose of the javadoc might both be internally facing (eg developers of the library/module), but also publicly (eg users of the library/module).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes. If it was aimed only towards users of the library/module I *think* only the "public for everyone" would be displayed since the modules of the user couldn't had been known during the library compile time. Not sure what it means for `protected` though.

Comment: it seems that javadoc is somehow equipped with *some* module documentation (I have not tried any of them). `javadoc --help | grep module` shows there are some options. From my understanding of these commands that are possible, there are somehow two types of documentation - the usual one and/or the modules. I might be entirely wrong... very good question indeed.

Answer (score 17):

javadoc has new options that allow you to select which items are documented at the module, package, type and member level. Using an EA version of JDK 9, look for new `--module`, `--show-*` options, and `--expand-requires` options.

The existing options `-public`, `-protected`, `-package`, `-private` options have been redefined in terms of the new `--show-*` options, although their command line help still needs to be updated.

The handy-dandy conversion table is:

```
-public
      --show-module-contents api --show-packages exported --show-types public --show-members public

-protected   (the long-standing default)
      --show-module-contents api --show-packages exported --show-types protected --show-members protected

-package
      --show-module-contents all --show-packages all --show-types package --show-members package

-private
      --show-module-contents all --show-packages all --show-types private --show-members private
```

In general, continue to use the default to generate documentation for users of an API, and maybe use `-package` or `-private` to generate documentation for the developers of an API. For more fine-grain control, use the underlying `--show-*` options.

Comment: How will the output change, if it will? Will different levels of `public` be noted in the Javadoc?